# Laravel 5.4 - Model accessor not working

Tags: php, laravel

I´ve been trying to make an accessor work a few hours now, to no avail. I have simplified my model code to the bare bones, and still no luck. 
Here´s the code in PersonaIdentificacion.php:`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PersonaIdentificacion extends Modelo
{
    public $table = "personaidentificacion";

    public function getFooAttribute() {
        return 1;
    }

}`
```

I use Artisan Tinker to try and retrieve the value of the 'foo' property, but I only get: 'null'. I don´t get it. What am I missing??

Comment: Is `Modelo` a typo? What code do you run in Tinker?

Comment: No. 'Modelo' is an extension of 'Model'. In there I have a few methods that are not directly related to this problem, or at least I think they don´t, since other models in my project use this same 'Modelo' and do not show this behavior.

Comment: What code do you run in Tinker?

Comment: In Tinker I type the following: $id = App\PersonaIdentificacion::first(); $id->foo;

Comment: Does `$id->getFooAttribute();` work?

Comment: Nope. BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getFooAttribute()'

Comment: Does it work outside of Tinker?

Comment: No. It doesn´t. I´ve even added the column in the DB table to see if something gets saved in there, but still nothing.

Comment: What's the result of `(new ReflectionClass(\App\PersonaIdentificacion::class))->getFileName();`?

Comment: It´s: "C:\wamp64\www\laravel\cte2\app\PersonaIdentificacion.php"

Comment: And `(new ReflectionClass($id))->getFileName();`?

Comment: Shows: PHP Notice: Undefined variable: id on line 1

Comment: `(new ReflectionClass(App\PersonaIdentificacion::first()))->getFileName();`

Comment: "C:\wamp64\www\larevel\cte2\app\PersonaIdentificacion.php"

Comment: Somehow Laravel is not using the `App\PersonaIdentificacion` code you posted. It's definitely located in `C:\wamp64\www\larevel\cte2\app\PersonaIdentificacion.php`?

Comment: Yes. I am sure. If for example, if while on Tinker, instead of $id->foo; I type $id->table, I get the correct 'personaidentificacion' table name. I have tried different 'names' for getNameAttribute(), and none of them work. In the application I get null values for any of them, even if I create the field in the table and assign some value to it, I still get nothing. I have just restarted my computer and ran config:clear and composer dumpautoload, and still the same... I´m bewildered...

Comment: Very strange. Try `extends Model` instead of `extends Modelo`.

Comment: Jonas, I´m really sorry. You are right. I was using the wrong file. Somehow I unwittingly made a copy of PersonaIdentificacion.php outside of the App folder and had been working on that file for a while,. No wonder it doesn´t work... Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Check your `namespace` and make sure you're using the right one.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonjie. Jonas Staudenmeir was right. I didn´t realize that I was working on the wrong file.

Answer (score 0):

Your getFooAttribute() is fine. 
To your model add the following assuming that it's a new attribute

```
 protected $appends=['foo'];
```

and then you can call

```
 $id = App\PersonaIdentificacion::first(); $id->foo;
```

This should work fine.

Comment: Thank you Athul. Jonas Staudenmeir made me realize that I was working on the wrong file. Now all is good.

Comment: oh.. glad you found the solution